# Remove mobile phone number or Update mobile phone number with empty string using microsoft graph api

Tags: python-3.x, microsoft-graph-api, azureportal

I am using Microsoft graph API and using 'users' resource. Endpoint is https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users. I am able to create user and update user's related field. Now I am trying to remove "mobilephone" number so, I sent empty string as a request info. but I am getting the following error.

Invalid value specified for property 'mobilePhone' of resource 'User'. "The mobilePhone should be between 1 and 64 characters.

Can I set empty string value to that field? How can I remove that field's value?

Comment: set it to 1 space? or remove the 1 to 16 validator and allow null values.

Comment: Thanks @PatrickArtner for your answer. How can I remove "1 to 16" validator? Where is the option located?

Answer (score 0):

```java
phoneNumber.replaceAll("[\\s\\-()]");
```

The regular expression defines a character class consisting of any whitespace character (`\s`, which is escaped as `\\s` because we're passing in a String)

Check [`String.replaceAll(String, String)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Thanks @PatrickArtner. Your solution resolve the issue. Thanks SaiSakethGuduru-MT to your answer.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can [accept it as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)( click on the checkmark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to fill in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you